# "Can't find variable: createStackNavigator"- React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Well, apparently there's an error in the eighth line and I cannot figure it out: "const Stack = createStackNavigator();".
I wanna know how could I fix it or if it actually is wrong. I honestly couldn't find the error.
It's about

````
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import * as React from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigation} from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const MyStack = () => {
    return(
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen 
                    name="Principal"
                    component={TelaPrincipal}
                    options={{title:'Bem Vindo à tela principal'}}
              ></Stack.Screen>
              <Stack.Screen 
                name="Tela02"
                component={Tela02}
                options={{title:'Bem Vindo à tela 02'}}
              ></Stack.Screen>
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
};
    const TelaPrincipal = ({navigation}) => {
        return(
            <View>
                <Button
                    title = 'Ir para Tela 02'
                    onPress= {() => navigation.navigate('Tela02', {name:'Tela02'})}
                ></Button>
            </View>
        );
    };
    const Tela02 = ({navigation}) => {
        return(
            <View>
                <Button
                    title = 'Ir para Tela Principal'
                    onPress= {() => navigation.navigate('TelaPrincipal', {name:'Principal'})}
                ></Button>
            </View>
        );
    };
export default MyStack;```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubReP.jpg
````

Comment: Your error does not correspond with the code your provide. You do `const Stack = createStackNavigation();`, not `const Stack = createStackNavigator();`

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to edit it when I realised. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured it out :)

I didn't import the right thingies.
It should be: "import {createStackNavigation, createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';".

It was missing an item.